# Sorting using spark

Tags: java, sorting, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I need to sort an RDD. The sort needs to be on multiple fields of my record and I hence need a custom Comparator.

I see that the `sortBy` as it accepts only a single key. I chanced upon http://codingjunkie.net/spark-secondary-sort/ and thus used `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` to achieve the same.

Why doesn't `sortBy` accept a custom Comparator and sort? Why do I have to repartition just inorder to user a custom Comparator?

Answer (score 1):

**Question1**: This is the **signature** of method `sortBy`:

```
  /**
   * Return this RDD sorted by the given key function.
   */
  def sortBy[K](
      f: (T) => K,
      ascending: Boolean = true,
      numPartitions: Int = this.partitions.length)
      (implicit ord: Ordering[K], ctag: ClassTag[K]): RDD[T] = withScope {
    this.keyBy[K](f)
        .sortByKey(ascending, numPartitions)
        .values
  }
```

> Your RDD data object is of type T, obviously

**Please note that sortBy method absolutely has single key parameter field:** `f: (T) => K`

It accept an **anonymous function**, so you can easily generate your custom comparable structure and make the most use of common data types that have their own well-defined comparator.

For example, if your RDD[Int, Int], we call it **data**, what you can do is as follow:

```
val cmp = (t: (Int, Int)) => (t._1, -t._2)
data.sortBy(cmp)
```

**This can achieve multi fields compare easily, right?**

> This will get an sorted RDD with first field ascend and second filed
>   descend.

**Question2**: repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions **usage**

This is a specific rdd operator aimed at more efficient than calling repartition and then sorting within each partition.

Your program need no pre-repartition before sort, it just internal optimization at this particular common pattern for high performance.

Please refer the [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) for details.

Comment: I use Java and I don't think I can write a lambda equivalent to `val cmp = (t: (Int, Int)) => (t._1, -t._2)`. The `sortBy` in Java allows me to pick up only one key to be used in sorting. Please refer to this, http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#sortBy-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function-boolean-int-

Answer (score 1):

> - mapPartitions to sort each partition using, for example, .sorted
> - repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions to efficiently sort partitions
>     while simultaneously repartitioning.
> - sortBy to make a globally ordered
>     RDD

- RDD's sortByKey method is using for total ordering
- RDD's repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is using sort within partition but not cross partitions, but unfortunately it adds an extra step to do repartition

As written in the Spark API, repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is more efficient than calling repartition and then sorting within each partition other words repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions will first repartition the data based on the provided partitioner, and then sort by the key:

> So first repartition and then call sortBy give you good performance
>   same you can achieve using repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions

Adding few Sorting examples hope it will help .

Ex 1

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
     |                ("math",    55),
     |                ("math",    56),
     |                ("english", 57),
     |                ("english", 58),
     |                ("science", 59),
     |                ("science", 54)))

rdd.collect()

//Default Sorting : Ascending order
val sorted1 = rdd.sortByKey()

 sorted1.collect()

 //Custom Sorting : Descending order (using implicit 'Ordering')
 {
     |    //Let us define an implicit sorting for the method sortByKey()
     |    //We have used '{' above to limit the scope of the implicit ordering
     |    implicit val sortIntegersByString = new Ordering[String] {
     |       override def compare(a: String, b: String) = {
     |          val result = a.compare(b)
     |          //We use -ve to sort the key in descending order
     |          -result
     |       }
     |    }
     |    val sorted2 = rdd.sortByKey()
     |
     |    //Result
     |    sorted2.collect()
     | }

//Default Sorting : Descending order (done using the 'ascending' flag argument)
 val sorted3 = rdd.sortByKey(false)

//Result
sorted3.collect()
```

**Result:**

```
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[101] at parallelize at command-1784487111427703:1
sorted1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[104] at sortByKey at command-1784487111427703:12
sorted3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[110] at sortByKey at command-1784487111427703:34
res28: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((science,59), (science,54), (math,55), (math,56), (english,57), (english,58))
```

Ex 2

```
case class Row(var firstName: String, var lastName: String, var city: String)

var rows = List(new Row("Oscar", "Wilde", "London"),
                new Row("Otto",  "Swift", "Berlin"),
                new Row("Carl",  "Swift", "Paris"),
                new Row("Hans",  "Swift", "Dublin"),
                new Row("Hugo",  "Swift", "Sligo"))

//print ("sort by last name")
//rows.sortBy(_.lastName)


print ("sort by last name and first name")

rows.sortBy(r => (r.lastName, r.firstName))



sort by last name and first namedefined class Row
rows: List[Row] = List(Row(Oscar,Wilde,London), Row(Otto,Swift,Berlin), Row(Carl,Swift,Paris), Row(Hans,Swift,Dublin), Row(Hugo,Swift,Sligo))
res26: List[Row] = List(Row(Carl,Swift,Paris), Row(Hans,Swift,Dublin), Row(Hugo,Swift,Sligo), Row(Otto,Swift,Berlin), Row(Oscar,Wilde,London))
```

**RDD vs Dataset:**

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
case class MyRecord(time: Double, id: String)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 200, 200).flatMap(x =>Seq.fill(10000)(MyRecord(util.Random.nextDouble, "xxx")))
// sort this RDD by time:
val sorted = rdd.sortBy(x => x.time)
result.count

// convert the original RDD to Dataframe and sort again:
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
df.registerTempTable("data")
val result = sqlContext.sql("select * from data order by time")
result.count
```